# Aura Component Date Rendering

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I have a component that is rendering some data from an object within `aura:iteration`.

I am trying to display the date in a more friendly format, but I am having trouble getting it to show up.

```
<div class="slds-media__body">
                <div
                  class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread slds-has-flexi-truncate"
                >
                  <p class="slds-text-body_small">
                    <a href="" title="{!c.CreatedById__r.Name__c}"
                      >{!c.CreatedById__r.Name__c}</a
                    >
                    —
                    <lightning:formattedDateTime
                      value="{!c.CreatedDate__c}"
                      year="numeric"
                      day="2-digit"
                      month="long"
                      hour="2-digit"
                      minute="2-digit"
                    />
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
```

I am trying to use `lightning:formattedDateTime` to achieve this. The field on the object is of type Date/Time.

The value that `{!CreatedDate__C}` prints outside of this is `2019-11-25T15:05:33.000Z`. However, when I try and render it within this component, there is no value printed.

Is there a way to call a method from the component within the iteration so I can convert this date another way?

Comment: `lightning:formattedDateTime` should work with a properly formatted ISO 8601 date string like `2019-11-25T15:05:33.000Z`.  Have you double-checked your variable names?  In your HTML you're referencing `{!c.CreatedDate__c}`, but in your narrative, you have `{!CreatedDate__C}`.

Comment: What is the name of the attribute here? You don't use `c` to print the values but to link to a controller? You seem to have some missing details here.

Comment: Might be good to see a little of your controller/helper code and also the iteration markup